# Dialogflow Routine suggestions - Trigger Add new Routine from agent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm building an agent which Send Daily updates and Routine suggestions.

Using Routine suggestions
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/routines

I was able to add my action to existing Routines of google Assistant.
Is there a way to provide user option to create a new routine with my action?

If not, is there any alternate methods to send updates to user by running CRON or something?

I tried Pushing notifications, but it didn't help since it's not updating voice commands in Google home.

Comment: Push notifications only work on phones, not on speakers.